# How to open new Terminal at currently open file in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I open a new terminal in VSCode, it opens at the base of my folder structure, and I have to `cd` multiple times to get to the file/directory I'm currently working. How do I default new terminals to start already in the directory of the file I currently have open?

Answer (score 0):

In your User Settings `settings.json` file, you can add the key `terminal.integrated.cwd` to determine the directory of a new terminal, i.e. `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "/user/name/my_folder"`

but you can also make the value a dynamic variable to open at the directory of the file current open like so: `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"`